# Xcode and iOS app data file placements defaults

Tags: ios, xcode

Is my understanding correct for iOS7-iOS9:

1)
"built-in" app cache path is **NSHomeDirectory() + "/Library/Caches/"**

2)
app launch images and icons are placed **NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!** (where does this map down to?)

3) a "blue" folder I have added in "xcode - build phases - copy bundle resources called "ownassets"" is placed in...? **NSHomeDirectory() + "/Library/"**

I am just tying to make **100%** sure if I understood correctly where files are placed, so I can read and load them during app execution (and write in my cache)

**Note:** I realize that *release code* should use system calls to get paths since Apple may changes paths in future iOS versions.

**Note** For hose looking on how to get normal IO file read access to folders and content you added in "Build phases > Copy Bundle Resources" this is how: NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath! + "/" + nameoffolder

Comment: Never use NSHomeDirectory to build a path.

Comment: Remember that URLs are preferred over paths these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not think much about the actual locations on disk, but use the higher-level system APIs to find files/paths:

1. Caches directory:

   ```
   let cacheURL = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.CachesDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
   ```
2. App resources in the bundle:

   - `let image = UIImage(named: "imageName")`
   - `let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("image", ofType: "png")`
3. App resources in subdirectories:

   ```
   let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("info", ofType: "dat", inDirectory: "AdditionalResources")
   ```

For more info, see [the File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4).

Comment: I understand (and will), but I am trying to understand it conceptionally (i.e. visualize it in my head how the file structure may look like like)

Comment: The article I linked to will answer those questions. `NSHomeDirectory()` is the application sandbox directory, while `NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL` is the app's bundle which contains resources you added at compile time.

Comment: Okay - from above link, I can see this "In iOS, Library is placed inside the apps data bundle.", so I guess "resourcePath" maps down to that (for now, I understand it may not be so in the future) - anyhow, i will test paths in a moment and report back what they were for reference

Comment: Actually, `resourcePath` is for compile-time resources like images, and other stuff returned by `pathForResource`. Why don't you test it out by `print()`ing these paths?

Comment: I will expand the question very soon